# FIlter a csv file with a list of search terms

Tags: python, csv, filter

I feel like I'm missing something. I have a csv file, and a list of search terms. I just want all rows of data in the csv file that meet a certain condition to be returned.

```
import csv
search = open("example.txt", "rb")
searchlist = []
for x in search:
    searchlist.append(x)

with open("test.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    rows = [row for row in reader]
```

I create two lists, one containing the search terms, the other containing every row of data of the csv file in a list.  I've tried for looping through them both but I feel like this isn't right:

```
for row in rows:
    for z in searchlist:
         if z not in row:
               print row
```

Feeling pretty stuck as to how to compare one list to another. If there's an easy way to do this/more pythonic way of writing it, I'd much appreciate an example, as well as why the code above doesn't work.

EDIT:

Okay all sorted thanks to all who inputted, adding finished code for reference:

```
import re

searchlist = []
with open("example.txt") as g:
    for line in g:
        searchlist.append(line.strip())

pattern = re.compile("|".join(searchlist))
with open("test.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(pattern,line):
            print line
            #line = line.split(",")
            #print line[5]
```

Comment: So you're trying to print the row for each searched item that it doesn't match?

Comment: @tom yeah so if the search terms defined are not in the row of data, return that row. but i guess it could be any conditional statement there?

Comment: And what behavior are you getting right now? It looks like it may print a given row multiple times--once for each searchlist item that it doesn't match. Is that what's happening? If so, and if that's not what you want, just add break after 'print row' and at the same indentation.

Comment: A csv row is a list... so, are you looking for a particular column (e.g., row[3]) in the search list?

Comment: @Tom...okay yeah that seems to work fine. is that all it takes? maybe I should read up about the break command. I take it there's a better way to do this? Right now it will match against exact matches in the csv file, so if i include something like "RIVERSIDE" it will only return results where the z = RIVERSIDE and not where z = RIVERSIDE BLVD. Which in fairness makes perfect sense. Would I need to use the regex module if i wanted "fuzzier" matches.Thanks for the help.

Comment: @tdelaney not a particular row, just across the sheet as a whole, I probably didn't need to read it in as a csv i guess, and it's a pretty inefficient way of searching.

Comment: You don't want the csv module as that gives you lists as rows

Comment: The `searchlist.append(x)` would be better written as `searchlist.append(x.strip())` to avoid newlines and whitespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

```
import re
...
pattern = re.compile("|".join(searchlist))
with open("your_file") as f:
    for line in f:
         if not re.search(pattern, line):
                print(line)
```

Comment: I would compile the regex once not every time you call it

Comment: This answer is better than mine, at least given the OP's later clarifications.

Comment: You can `pattern.search(row)`,  the OP would also be better using   `file.open` as the csv module is going to return lists for rows not strings

Comment: @aaron_world_traveler

hmm i get a "expected string or buffer" error when trying this. This will be to do with the data in rows being in lists? maybe. I originally opened the file with csv reader because my plan was to filter, then print specific columns print row[0], row[4] etc.

Comment: Yes, that's probably why its failing.  If row is truly a list of strings, just do something like `",".join(row)` instead of just `row` within the re.search call.

Comment: @user3244770, don't use the csv module at all, it makes no sense at all to use the csv module to split  then join.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham okay got it. then split line on  "," to access the individual elements. thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Since it worked for you, I'm adding it as an answer so you can mark it:

```
for row in rows:
    for z in searchlist:
         if z not in row:
               print row
               break
```

There are multiple ways to do "fuzzier" matches. It just depends on what you're going for.